# Struggling to identify the solution to this error

Tags: php, forms

I am getting this error when my form is completed, despite the fact that the successful response is correctly displayed and the item is added to the database.

Here's the error

> Warning: mysql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/site4/public_html/lab/mailinglist/mailing_list_external.php on line 18

Line 18 is

```
mysql_free_result($check_res);
```

and the entire PHP file is

```
    <?php
include("mailing_list_include.php");
// determine if they need to see the form or not

if ($_POST["email"] == "") {
    header("Location: mailing_list_external.php");
    exit;
} else {
    // connect to database
    doDB();

    // check that the email is in list
    emailChecker($_POST["email"]);

    // get number of results and do action
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_res) < 1) {
        // free result
        mysql_free_result($check_res); 

        // add record
        $add_sql =  "INSERT INTO subscribers (email)
                    VALUES('".$_POST["email"]."')";
        $add_res =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_sql)
                    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $display_block = "<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>";

        // close connection to mysql
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
    } else {
        // print failure message
        $display_block = "<p>You're already subscribed!</p>";

    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "$display_block"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, it works fine but I still get this error...

Here's the code for the included file (mailing_list_include.php)

```
    <?php

function doDB() {
global $mysqli;

// connect to server and select database; you may need it
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX",
    "XXX", "XXX");

    // if connection fails, stop script execution
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}
}

function emailChecker($email) {
global $mysqli, $check_res;

//check that email is not already in list
$check_sql = "SELECT id FROM subscribers
    WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$check_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_sql)
    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post *complete* source code. Where does `$check_res` come from?

Comment: Stupid me, adding the include code now :)

Comment: Everything else is using mysqli_ prefixed functions, why are you using mysql_ in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'm learning PHP if that isn't obvious so the help is appreciated :)

Comment: Well to be honest I have never used mysql_free_result in any of my code. The life of a script is usually so short, that unless you are dealing with huge datasets and doing a lot of processing, there is very little need to free the result. As the process of ending the script will get rid of it, and close the connection to the database anyway

Comment: Presumably I need to build in a check that protects against anything malicious being entered. A check to confirm it's an email address would be sufficient?

Comment: To protect against malicious input, see http://nz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: I added FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL to my code, is that sufficient? It seems to filter out non email characters and insists that the format of an email address is adhered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli_free_result - I suspect it's because you're using mysql_free_result, which is a different library

Comment: I think the same thing but mysqli_free_result doesn't exist

Comment: i look for it in the site and i didn't find that, spooky! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysqli i think that you should use [mysqli_close()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) to close the connection or [mysqli_free_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

```
 mysqli_free_result($check_res);
```

here you are using a function from another library

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is just your basic script that registers a user and sends an email then you can fix your problem by eliminating the _free_result and the _close calls completely.  They really serve no useful purpose unless you are dealing with thousands of records in one request.

In php, all resources are automatically freed up when the script finishes.